# React Native: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/iid/zzc.class

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm developing a project on react native and the same code that was working a day ago no longer works. Here are my build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile project(':react-native-audio')
compile project(':react-native-fcm')
compile project(':bugsnag-react-native')
compile project(':react-native-code-push')
compile project(':react-native-mixpanel')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
compile project(':react-native-permissions')
compile project(':react-native-maps')
compile project(':react-native-device-info')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1') {
    force = true;
}

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" 
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1') {
    force = true;
}
compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1") {
    force = true;
}

compile project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:0.11.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.13.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:0.11.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:0.11.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:0.11.0'
```

Please let me know if I've gone wrong with any of the dependencies.

Here is the full error:

```
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/iid/zzc.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.05 secs
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. There was a mismatch in Google Play services versions across the dependencies. Upgraded everything the latest value and things are now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps` is duplicated because it's already included in `react-native-maps` with a different version.

You can safely remove it.

Answer (score 0):

in libraries `react-native-maps` and  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps`their is dublicated classes so you have to exclude `zzc.class` from in the android gradle