# Ionic Background Geolocation plugin causes error when building

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 2 app that worked fine. Now I made an update and when I try to build the APK I get an error.

```
* What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
        > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 
        com/google/android/gms/iid/zzc.class
```

The error tells me the problem but I don't know how to solve it. Where do I have to remove the duplicate?

This is related to the Ionic Background Geolocation plugin because if I remove that plugin the issue disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background geolocation plugin [depends on the Play Services library](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/blob/master/plugin.xml#L30) and the error message you posted above is indicative of a mismatch in versions of the Play Services library specified in the Gradle configuration ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45487369/777265) for a similar error). The likely cause is that you have another plugin in your project specifying a different Play Services version. The background geolocation plugin is specifying `+`, i.e. the most recent version ([v11.6.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_6_2017_-_version_1160)).

A possible solution is to install the [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) plugin into your project, which attempts to override the versions specified by plugins to resolve version collisions.

The background geolocation plugin [also depends on the Android Support library](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/blob/master/plugin.xml#L31), so after fixing the Play Services issue, you may encounter a similar problem with this. If so, you can try to use [cordova-android-support-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release) to perform a similar override in the Gradle config.